# What is the cost of unnamed scope in C?

Tags: c, performance

I was playing with C++ earlier and was thinking if, in some cases, Since my C compiler refuses to let me write code such as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
{
   ...
}
```

I try writing something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 30; ++i) {
            printf("%d.\n", i);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The result is that I do not have this i variable in my scope for more than I need it for, and frees up i to be used for other purposes in the main scope (i wouldn't do this to i, since it's iterator by convention). So I am allowed to write silly code like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i = 3;

    /* my loop scope. */
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 30; ++i) {
            printf("%d.\n", i);
        }
    }
    printf("i remains intact! %d.\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

Again, I would not intentionally make real code to abuse i like this, but in many cases, especially dealing with temporary variables necessary in libc function calls, such as [sem_getvalue](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sem_getvalue.html) or Windows API [FormatMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351(v=vs.85).aspx), where it is easy to clutter up the scope with many temp variables and get confused with what's going on. By using unnamed scopes, In theory, I could reduce complexity of my code by isolating these temporary variables to unnamed scopes.

The idea seems silly but compelling and I am curious if there is any cost/drawback to writing code in this style. Is there inherent issues with writing code this way, or is this a decent practice?

Comment: Please get a C99 compiler for `for`-scoped variables. They're not that rare.

Comment: I was interested in using unnamed scopes for temp variables required to be made before function calls that store results of  those functions as well. I'm just interested in the unnamed construct by itself, is there any particular reason to avoid it?

Comment: The "cost" of declaring variables in a nested scope is the storage space of those variables. That's about it.

Comment: That would mean no cost, since that variable(i/temp) would have been used regardless, and when it leaves the scope it would actually save me stack space once it leaves the scope by removing itself. Is this really the case?

Comment: Regarding saving stack space when leaving the nested scope, nope that won't happen. No normal compiler would "push" or "pop" the stack when entering or leaving nested scopes, instead it creates space for *all* variables in a function when calling or entering the function (depending on calling conversion and ABI), no matter the scope. Scope doesn't really exist in the generated code, it's a construct used only by the programmer and the compiler.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i)` is perfectly valid standard C.

Comment: @lurker: "In gcc you have to enable that standard explicitly" is wrong for gcc since version 5.

Comment: @Olaf thanks for that. I think I'm running version < 5.

Comment: Some of your assumptions might have been true >20 years ago. They are neither mandated by the standard, nor are they necessarily true for a halfway modern compiler. They heavily depend on the target architecture anyway.

Comment: The unix shell I use has gcc 4.7.2. I know I can enable the feature, I am interested in the theory behind the question.

Comment: @lurker: Me too. gcc 5.x uses `gnu11` by default, the older versions `gnu90`. C99 was actually skipped (maybe they just "forgot" to update the default:).

Comment: @Olaf I was wrong anyway, so the point is, kind of, moot. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{
  int x = 3;
  {
     int y = 4;
     int sum = x+y;
  }
}
```

Has no more cost than:

```
{
  int x = 3;
  int y = 4;
  int sum = x+y;
}
```

Because braces do not translate into any machine code themselves, they are just there to tell the compiler about scope.

The fact your variables have the same name also has no effect because variable names are also just for the compiler and do not change machine code.

Comment: I was thinking that, but it seemed too good to be true, since once y and sum leave the scope, they should no longer be taking up any stack space(in contrast to a full-scope variable that lasts throughout the whole scope even after it's no longer needed), since they pop themselves off the stack when the scope exits. Is  this really the case?

Comment: I think it's not worth thinking that way because you'll be wrong 9 times out of 10. The compiler is able to in line methods and reuse stack space, so you can never predict what will really happen. e.g. `sum` in my example might actually be in the same stack space as `x` because `x` is not used again afterwards.

Comment: But assuming no optimizations, would that be the case?

Comment: Maybe, but I don't think you can care about stack space and have optimisations off.

Comment: I understand that, I was just really curious how it behaved. Since there is no drawback to using it, I am more confident in using it when I feel it's warranted. I think this answers it though.

Comment: Yes fair enough to be curious. It's a compiler implementation detail, so no one definitive answer.

Answer (score 4):

> frees up i to be used for other purposes in the main scope

This is the flaw in your reasoning. You should not use a variable with the same name for unrelated purposes inside the same function. Apart from making the code unreadable, it opens up for all kinds of subtle bugs. Copy/paste one snippet and put it elsewhere in the function, and suddenly it is working with another variable. That is very bad practice, period.

Similarly, it is most often bad practice to have variables in different scopes but with the same name.

If you have multiple loops in the same function that all uses an interator `i` with the same type, simply declare it at the beginning of the function and re-use it over and over.

If you need an `i` with different type at different places in a function, that's a clear sign saying that you should split the function in several.

Overall, whenever you find yourself in need to use an obscure language mechanism, you need to step back and consider if you couldn't just design the program in a simpler way. This is almost always the case. Excellent programmers always strive for simplicity and never for complexity.

Comment: I am well aware of that. My question was regarding what the cost of using the construct is. Hence my intent is to use it when I feel it is warranted. Just because I have flexibility to do so doesn't mean I'll use it like that everywhere to obfuscate conventional variables and my code. But this technique seems interesting to apply when dealing with temporary variables such as sem_getvalue integer, and lpBuffer in FormatMessage(Windows API). Doing so simplifies my code by eliminating temporary variables from local scope into a temporary scope.

Comment: @Dmitry Scope and storage are two different things. In terms of efficiency, there is no cost. The compiler will allocate space when needed, and free it when needed, _regardless of where a certain variable is declared_. Scope is only about restricting variables for intentional/unintentional use outside of the code where it makes sense to use that variable.

Comment: That's my point. These temporary variables make no sense to be used outside that scope, they only confuse/overwhelm the reader by increasing amount of variables in the local scope. I was curious if using it for this purpose had any cost to it that I was unaware of. From what I gather, this seems like an ideal solution for reducing scope clutter by moving it into temporary scopes where they are meaningful.

Comment: @Dmitry If you have so many variables that the reader gets confused/overwhelmed by the sheer amount of them, then that's a 100% certain proof that your function is way too complex and must get split into several. Again, strive for simplicity not complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think local variable allocation works how you think it does.

The compiler maps all the local variables memory requirements together and on entry to the function allocates an offset of that amount on the stack at one time regardless of how many you have. So allocating 20 variables takes the same time as 1.